# go Lang load unable to process yaml file

Tags: go

I am trying to read a yaml file and store it in a variable but for some reason the array object in YAML file is unable to unmarshall the file. it shows blank data.

Below is my yaml file content

```
---
version: "1.2"

bUnits:
  - name: buname
    buGroupID: asd
    buStGroupID: asd
  - name: buname2
    buGroupID: asd2
    buStGroupID: asd2
```

Below is the code that am using

```
type SResponse struct {
   Version       string         `json:"version"`
   BUnits []BUnit `json:"bUnits"`
}

type BUnit struct {
    Name                      string `json:"name"`
    BuUnitGroupID       string `json:"buGroupID"`
    BuUnitStGroupID string `json:"buStaticGroupID"`
}
func main() {

    _printf := fmt.Printf
    _printf("Start")
    var sListResponse SResponse

    source, err2 := ioutil.ReadFile("squads2.yml")

    if err2 != nil {
        _printf("Couldn't read yaml file.")
}

    err2 = yaml.Unmarshal(source, &sListResponse)
    if err2 != nil {
    _printf("Error")
    }

    _printf("Output: %s\n", sListResponse)
}
```

The code reads version part but the bUnits array comes empty.Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your structs are decorated with `json` tags - which you may or may not need (depending on if you are exporting/import this data in JSON later).
But your problem at hand is with `yaml` importing - so you need to decorate your `struct` definitions with `yaml` tags.

To support both `json` and `yaml` marshaling/unmarshaling, simply update your tags like so:

```
type SResponse struct {
    Version string  `json:"version" yaml:"version"`
    BUnits  []BUnit `json:"bUnits" yaml:"bUnits"`
}

type BUnit struct {
    Name            string `json:"name" yaml:"name"`
    BuUnitGroupID   string `json:"buGroupID" yaml:"buGroupID"`
    BuUnitStGroupID string `json:"buStaticGroupID" yaml:"buStaticGroupID"`
}
```

Or just drop the `json` tags if you have no need for JSON encoding/decoding.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `yaml` tag in your struct

```
type SResponse struct {
    Version string  `yaml:"version"`
    BUnits  []BUnit `yaml:"bUnits"`
}

type BUnit struct {
    Name            string `yaml:"name"`
    BuUnitGroupID   string `yaml:"buGroupID"`
    BuUnitStGroupID string `yaml:"buStaticGroupID"`
}
```